# IIS on windows 10 application pool keeps stopping

Tags: iis

I am having an issue with IIS resulting in the app pool stopping, so I am getting a 503 error

**Event Viewer reports**
*Windows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded. Check that you are connected to the network, and that your network is functioning correctly.
DETAIL - Access is denied.
Windows has backed up this user profile. Windows will automatically try to use the backup profile the next time this user logs on.
Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.*

I believe this may be because I followed instructions I found on google to clear down files from AppData amongst other place, last week when C: became full (bad move ).  Sadly, there is no backup to reinstate the lost files.  I expect I have removed an account or permissions somehow.

I have tried setting **Load User Profile** to False and also setting **Identity** to LocalSystem but not allowed these settings in the app pool

I was hoping to reinstall IIS but cannot find a solution for that. Does anyone please have advice?

Comment: In such a situation, build another machine and copy whatever meaningful (IIS site configuration and web contents) over. That might help you recover the site on that new machine. It will be too late to work on this one after you followed some unknown instructions found. Next time, give less trust to search results as the authors (if not from Microsoft) might totally have no idea what they were writing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have the code for the site just think I am missing some user details for IIS

Comment: According to your error message, the problem cannot be reproduced because you don’t know which configuration files you cleared. As Lex Li suggested, it is a good choice to build a new machine and copy the contents.